# $SO(3)$ and twisting the 2-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, spheres

I am currently reading some parts of "Rotating Relativistic Stars" by Friedman and Stergioulas and I have to say mathematics should NOT be taught by astrophysicists... Anyway, I've encountered the term "rotational scalar" and it raised a lot of questions. It all boils down to one big question in the end...

Consider a 2-sphere in a spherically symmetric 4D manifold. SO(3) acts on the manifold via some diffeomorphisms. I've tried to come up with a diffeomorphism that preserves the spherical symmetry but is not in SO(3). A candidate is a mapping that rotates the sphere around an axis, but with varying angular velocity (twisting the sphere). Is it possible to construct such a mapping so that it is a diffeomorphism and does it preserve the spherical symmetry? If it is possible, is such a diffeomorphism a part of SO(3)?

I am not really sure I myself understand my question, but let's start a discussion and see... Trying to ask this helps anyway :)

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. Do you want a diffeomorphism of $S^2$ that's not in $SO(3)$? There are many. Do you want an isometry? Then there are essentially none - the isometry group of $S^2$ is $O(3)$.

Comment: Actually I've thought about this and I think an isometry is what I want. Because it needs to preserve the spherical symmetry, i. e. the metric on the submanifolds needs to be that of a sphere.